# WSO2 ESB configuration with SAP adapter to send IDoc

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, jco

I am trying to configure SAP adapter with WSO2 ESB. I have followed the instructions mentioned on WSO2 website: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/SAP+Integration

But when I start the WSO2 ESB, it is giving Exception:

```
waqasalirazaq@wi3-Inspiron-3521:~/Documents/WSO2/wso2esb-4.8.1/bin$ ./wso2server.sh
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to /home/waqasalirazaq/jdk1.7.0_51
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to /home/waqasalirazaq/Documents/WSO2/wso2esb-4.8.1
[2014-11-03 16:49:39,599]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Starting WSO2 Carbon...
[2014-11-03 16:49:39,603]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Operating System : Linux 3.2.0-68-generic, amd64
[2014-11-03 16:49:39,604]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Home        : /home/waqasalirazaq/jdk1.7.0_51/jre
[2014-11-03 16:49:39,604]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Version     : 1.7.0_51
[2014-11-03 16:49:39,604]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java VM          : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 24.51-b03,Oracle Corporation
[2014-11-03 16:49:39,604]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Carbon Home      : /home/waqasalirazaq/Documents/WSO2/wso2esb-4.8.1
[2014-11-03 16:49:39,604]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Temp Dir    : /home/waqasalirazaq/Documents/WSO2/wso2esb-4.8.1/tmp
[2014-11-03 16:49:39,605]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator User             : waqasalirazaq, en-US, Asia/Karachi
[2014-11-03 16:49:39,702]  WARN - ValidationResultPrinter The default keystore (wso2carbon.jks) is currently being used. To maximize security when deploying to a production environment, configure a new keystore with a unique password in the production server profile.
[2014-11-03 16:49:39,714]  INFO - AgentHolder Agent created !
[2014-11-03 16:49:39,745]  INFO - AgentDS Successfully deployed Agent Client
[2014-11-03 16:49:44,606]  INFO - EmbeddedRegistryService Configured Registry in 116ms
[2014-11-03 16:49:44,786]  INFO - RegistryCoreServiceComponent Registry Mode    : READ-WRITE
[2014-11-03 16:49:45,440]  INFO - UserStoreMgtDSComponent Carbon UserStoreMgtDSComponent activated successfully.
[2014-11-03 16:49:52,275]  INFO - TaglibUriRule TLD skipped. URI: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles is already defined
[2014-11-03 16:49:53,700]  INFO - ClusterBuilder Clustering has been disabled
[2014-11-03 16:49:54,223]  INFO - LandingPageWebappDeployer Deployed product landing page webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/home]
[2014-11-03 16:49:54,224]  INFO - UserStoreConfigurationDeployer User Store Configuration Deployer initiated.
[2014-11-03 16:49:54,310]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSSLSender Initializing Pass-through HTTP/S Sender...
[2014-11-03 16:49:54,343]  INFO - ClientConnFactoryBuilder HTTPS Loading Identity Keystore from : repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks
[2014-11-03 16:49:54,352]  INFO - ClientConnFactoryBuilder HTTPS Loading Trust Keystore from : repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks
[2014-11-03 16:49:54,406]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSSLSender Pass-through HTTPS Sender started...
[2014-11-03 16:49:54,407]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSender Initializing Pass-through HTTP/S Sender...
[2014-11-03 16:49:54,412]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSender Pass-through HTTP Sender started...
[2014-11-03 16:49:54,416]  INFO - JMSSender JMS Sender started
[2014-11-03 16:49:54,418]  INFO - JMSSender JMS Transport Sender initialized...
[2014-11-03 16:49:54,419]  INFO - SAPTransportSender BAPI Sender started
[2014-11-03 16:49:54,422] FATAL - CarbonServerManager WSO2 Carbon initialization Failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sap.conn.jco.ext.Environment.isServerDataProviderRegistered()Z
    at org.wso2.carbon.transports.sap.SAPTransportSender.init(SAPTransportSender.java:84)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.initTransportSenders(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:300)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.init(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:231)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:93)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.CarbonConfigurationContextFactory.createNewConfigurationContext(CarbonConfigurationContextFactory.java:65)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:398)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.start(CarbonServerManager.java:219)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreServiceComponent.activate(CarbonCoreServiceComponent.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.registerHttpService(Activator.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.addProxyServlet(Activator.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.init(ProxyServlet.java:40)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.init(DelegationServlet.java:38)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1186)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1081)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolve this issue by placing the Jars (sapjco3.jar & sapidoc3.jar) in /repository/component/lib and JCO native library (sapjco3.so) in /jre/lib/amd64